# Google Analytics Custom Dimensions and Metrics are missing! Android SDK 2.0

Tags: google-analytics

I am currently trying to set up tracking for a group of Android apps with the Google Analytics (GA) SDK 2.0.

Most of it is working fine, but i want to track some things with Custom Dimensions and Metrics. I have already set these things up on the earlier SDK using Custom Variables without any problem but with the new SDK the Custom Variables are replaced by Custom Dimensions and Metrics. These have to be created in the GA interface and then called in the app.

Unfortunately they are not available in my interface, and so I cant set them up.
Also there is not really much on the web at the moment about this problem so it may be that i need to set something up first to have access to these in my interface, which i dont know about.

Does anyone have a solution to this problem? Is anyone else facing the same thing?

Answer (score 0):

Custom Dimensions are configured at the PROPERTY level, not the profile level

[image]